# I want to start system application activity in broadcast onReceive() methord

Tags: android

I want to start a system application activity in a broadcast onReceive() method, but it cannot be run. I need help！
My Manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My java:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent b_intent = new Intent();
        b_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.email", "com.android.email.activity.Welcome"));
        b_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(b_intent);

    }
}
```

But this email application can not be run. There is only black color on the screen.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent i = new Intent()
i.setClassName("com.android.email", "com.android.email.activity.Welcome");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Launching system or third party apps from your app should be done through implicit intents. Hard-coding the package names and component names is not reliable and may not work all the time.

Morever, this particular activity, I guess, is not allowed to be called from other apps (my assumption, I might be wrong)

Comment: Post some logs. Well, as I said, this method is not reliable.